# How to use javascript on nodejs and web at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

i want to use a config file in nodejs and in a web javascript.

config.js:

```
var conf = {};

conf.name = 'testname';
conf.pass = 'abc123';
conf.ip = '0.0.0.0';
conf.port = 100;
conf.delay = 5;

exports.config = conf;
```

use it in nodejs with:

```
var conf = require('config.js');
console.log(conf.config.name);
```

want to use this same file inside html but how? I was thinking by this way but i don't know how to use it in web. When i try to use it in web i get Reference error: exports is not defined.

config.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="./config.js"></script>
    <script>
        var cnf = conf;
        function getCnf(){
            alert(cnf.config.name);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="getCnf();">test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone know how i must change config.js to use it in both systems nodejs and web?

PS: Webside is running on nodejs http npm module.

Comment: don't expose configuration to client-side this way, you can easily make a route and check if visitor has admin privileges or no and serve it a JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a condition around that, like this

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    module.exports.config = conf;
}
```

This makes sure that you have `module` and `exports` are available before setting any value on `exports`.

**Note:** `exports` is just another variable referring `module.exports`. So, they both are one and the same unless you assign something else to either of them. In case, you assign something to either of them, whatever is there in `module.exports` will be exported in Node.js. You can read more about `exports` in this [blog post](http://www.thefourtheye.in/2014/03/nodejs-modules-and-exports.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) to bundle your CommonJS for the browser without resorting to environment switches.

1. Install browserify using `npm i browserify -g`
2. Bundle your `config.js` and export it for external use with the `-r` tag

   `browserify -r ./config.js -o bundle.js`
3. Include the bundle in your code and use it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
        var cnf = require("./config.js");
        function getCnf(){
            alert(cnf.config.name);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="getCnf();">test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that typeof was all i needed.

@Phoenix: I know that there is a way to do that but that's not necessary. The variable are only used for some ajax requests and deley timers later.