# How to create a library to use in web and nodejs

Tags: typescript

I'm developing a library and I would like to know how can I do to use it in web (html) and as a library in nodejs.

My main question is about modules, i don't know which to use, external or internal. What I see right now is that internal modules is used for web and external can be used in nodejs.

My question is similar to that: [How to use javascript on nodejs and web at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891526/how-to-use-javascript-on-nodejs-and-web-at-the-same-time)

How can I do to make it possible to use in both?

Answer (score 0):

> i don't know which to use, external or internal. What I see right now is that internal modules is used for web and external can be used in nodejs.

Use `commonjs`. Don't use any `node` specific stuff in your code (e.g. don't do `require('fs')`. Then publish to NPM. This way it will work as it is for NodeJS users.

Since you didn't use any node specific stuff .... it will work *as it is* for webpack (or browserify) users too!